# Hacker Rank Exercise For Asterisks square

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm currently doing this exercise, and as far as I know, the code is correct.
However, for some reason HackerRank is either, saying that result is Not a Number(NaN), or there is not output on sdtout.
I have no idea what to do.
I know this have something to deal with the fact that HackerRank has an "expected" way of writing the code, so it can pass the values, but I don't understand.
e.g. quadrado means square, and linha line.
The function prints an square of asterisks.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function(inputStdin) {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.split('\n');

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}



function imprimaQuadradoAsterisco(n) {
// não altere a linha acima
    
/*
 * Escreva nas linhas a seguir um código que 
 * imprima um quadrado de asteríscos
 * de altura e largura igual ao valor de n
 */
if ( n >= 0){
    let asterisco = "*";
    let linha = asterisco * n;
    let quadrado = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        quadrado += linha + "\n";
}   
    return quadrado;
    
} else {
    return "Somente números maiores ou igual a 0";
}
  console.log(imprimaQuadradoAsterisco(n));  
    
    
// não altere a linha abaixo
}

// fim do seu código
```

I tried many ways of doing the code, however my problem is how hackerrank deals with the input of information for the code. I don't think the problem is necessary the code itself, but might be wrong.

Comment: Link to the challenge so that people have some idea what your code is supposed to do

Comment: The problem isn't how Hackerrank expects the output. The problem is that your code is wrong. You should step line by line with your debugger through the code and analyze it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the multiplication operator (`*`) to repeat strings (like you can in Python). Instead, use [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).

```js
let linha = asterisco.repeat(n);
```

Comment: l already tried this. doenst work either

Comment: @GabrielGuerreiro There are other issues with your code then. You should move `let quadrado = "";` into the first line of the function, outside the `if` statement.

Comment: thanks for the help. but it also doesnt work